# how to render an array of JSX using .map in react

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, loops, jsx

I have an array of objects like the following:

```js
const features = [
{
        name: "Sponsor Block",
        images: [sponsorBlock1, sponsorBlock2],
        data: [
            `Uses the API found ${<a href='example.com/'>here</a>}. You can find more information on how it works`,
            "Lorem ipsum ........"
        ],
    },
]
```

In the first point you can see that I am using a template string to inject JSX (I'm not sure if this is the right way to do this)

I want to map (loop) over the features array and display the first point with the anchor tag in it, and the other points that are just text as normal text.

But when I loop over the data key in the first object I get this displayed in my JSX-> [Object][Object]

Is there a way how I can solve this while still keeping it inside the array?

Comment: What are you trying to display that you get `[Object][Object]`? Please show a reproducible example [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Could you provide what do you want to show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not simply An array of fragment components

```
data:[
    <>Uses the API found <a href='example.com/'>here</a>. You can find more information on how it works</>,
    <>Lorem ipsum ........</>
]
```

Then when you render do:

```
return (
    <ul>
        {features.data.map((d,i)=><li key={i}>{d}</li>}
    </ul>
)
```

Comment: One little thing is that you don't have keys for elements returned from your API. If you use indexes for key this might cause errors when you remove or add elements to your array.

Answer (score -4):

```js
const features = [
{
        name: "Sponsor Block",
        images: [sponsorBlock1, sponsorBlock2],
        data: [
            `Uses the API found <a href='example.com/'>here</a>. You can find more information on how it works`,
            "Lorem ipsum ........"
        ],
    },
]

features.map(feature => {
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: feature.data }} />
})
```

Comment: It's a security risk to use dangerouslySetInnerHTML in react. check this out https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml

Comment: I know, but if it's not user data,  this doesn't matter.